# Eclipse keeps crashing?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I already am awaiting a reply from the Eclipse staff as they are having some bug issue with my account on their website, in the meantime, maybe someone here can shed some light onto this issue.

Basically, I am just starting with C++ and I installed the CDT and MinGW. I followed my professors instructions and got it successfully installed (tested the installation via the command line with a premade file). Anyways I tried to save/compile within Eclipse and it crashed on me, and ever since then it wont even start up now. It loads the interface for Eclipse but within 1-5 seconds it will crash with the same error.

Not sure what is going on, any help appreciated, attached is the image of the error.
Using Eclipse Juno

[image: http://i421.photobucket.com/albums/pp296/rskom/errorJuno.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that the Eclipse plugin CDT has an issue with JDK 1.6, I uninstalled 1.6 and downloaded 1.7 and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try running eclipse with the -clean option: i.e. `c:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, the issue was with JDK version and CDT for Eclipse